# Is it permitted for Jewish lawyers to defend those they believe to be guilty?

Tags: halacha, employment, criminal-procedure

I am in (secular) law school and am exploring my professional options. One of those options is to become a criminal defence attorney.

In my country of residence, attorneys qualified in a specific area of law are forbidden from rejecting clients on the basis that they are notorious or highly suspected of being guilty. If I am approached by a potential client who is able to pay my standard rate, and I am physically available to defend the person and am knowledgable in the relevant area of law, I am legally required to defend the individual.

Thus, it is possible that I would be legally required to defend someone who has violated one of the Noachide laws, etc. It is possible that in doing so, someone who I suspect is guilty would be acquitted on the basis of issues with the prosecution, in accordance with the laws of my country of residence. Although it is unlawful for me to lie in court, if a client who I suspect is guilty claims he is innocent, I would be required to try to make that case to the best of my ability.

What are my obligations in regards to Halacha, if I were to become a criminal defence attorney? I am aware that as a Jew I am required to distance myself from untruth, etc. Am I permitted to defend such people? What if, for example, such a person has clearly violated a Noachide law or harmed a Jew, but could be acquitted as a result of the prosecution having illegally obtained all of the evidence?

Comment: RFP? [15charachters]

Comment: @dou yes indeed imo

Comment: Sorry, what is the meaning of RFP?

Comment: If the prosecution has broken the law, then technically the defendant is not criminally liable. As such you should be allowed to defend his **as long as you are not lying**

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a psak halacha. For that one must consult a rabbi, not rely on a website.

Answer (score -1):

Whether your client is actually guilty or not, should be immaterial.

When defending a person in secular court, your job is to make sure to hold the prosecution to the prevalent laws of the land, and require it to prove its case against the defendant, in court, and beyond a reasonable doubt.

If you can do so, without saying any untruth, then you should be able to take the case. You can always say, "The defendant claims...", which is not that you're vouching for its veracity, just that your presenting his claim to the court.

[One source - see #10](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/23379)

[Note #5 - in the name of Rabbi Aaron Lichtenstein](https://www.toraland.org.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98/%D7%90%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98/%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F/)

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: This article also mentions the principle of לא תעמוד על דם רעך - would this mean that if the defendant is potentially dangerous, one has a positive obligation to see to it that they are imprisoned if they know them to be guilty, regardless of obligations to apply the laws of the land (Eg. Suppose a police officer conducted a search without a warrent, which demonstrated guilt, but the evidence is inadmissible in court) ? Does Halacha prioritize the fulfilment of this mitzvah, or the necessity of following a country's laws?

Comment: we need to know more about the exact parameters of the obligation of לא תעמוד על דם רעך. Is there currently a real credible threat to anyone's life, because this person is walking free? Even if a person might have committed a crime in the past, who says that he will be a repeat offender?

Comment: The second article link does not support your claim, and note #5 is irrelevant here.

Comment: @simyou We can agree to disagree about note #5. Rabbi Aaron Lichtenstein allegedly sees no major problem in serving as a defense attorney in criminal cases, without ANY qualifier. This, despite the fact there's a distinct possibility that the lawyer might suspect that the defendant actually did commit the crime.

Comment: That's not even what note 5 says. It cites RAL in support of the sentence "In fields such as real estate, traffic, taxes and criminal law, the problems don't exist or exists to a smaller degree because in those fields even halakha agrees that we follow state laws". That's not what you said

Comment: @DoubleAA The context of Rabbi Aaron Lichtenstein's words were regarding possible Halachic issues of practicing law. In that context, he included criminal law as a permitted field of endeavor.

Comment: As a permitted or less prohibited field, without mentioning your reasoning at all

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that he doesn't mention my reasoning, which stands as an independent point of logic. I merely intended to cite him as a support to the permissibility of practicing law in this field.

Comment: ...the permissibility or not so prohibitability of practicing law in this field. Your post is quite unclear about what he says and what you think that supports

Answer (score -1):

In [Rambam's Mishneh Torah Hilchos Sanhedrin chapter 26 halacha 7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172749/jewish/Sanhedrin-vehaOnashin-haMesurin-lahem-Chapter-26.htm), it says the following:

> 7
>
> When any person has a judgment adjudicated by gentile judges and their
>   courts, he is considered a wicked person. It is as if he disgraced,
>   blasphemed, and lifted up his hand against the Torah of Moses our
>   teacher. This applies even if their laws are the same as the laws of
>   the Jewish people. This is indicated by Exodus 21:1: "These are the
>   judgments that you shall place before them." "Before them" and not
>   before gentiles; "before them" and not before ordinary people.
>
> The following procedure should be carried out if the gentiles have a
>   powerful law enforcement system and the opposing litigant is a
>   stubborn and powerful person from whom one cannot expropriate property
>   through the judicial system of the Jewish people. One should summon
>   him before the Jewish judges first. If he did not desire to come, one
>   may receive license from the court and salvage one's property from the
>   litigant by having the case tried in a gentile court.

it seems pretty clear that if even bringing a case to non-jewish court is problematic, for sure defending someone in it without legitimate cause. However, in the second paragraph of the above-quoted Rambam, as well as in the Shulchan Aruch Chosen Mishpat chapter 26 it says that there is at least one case where it's permitted to go to secular court:

> היתה יד עכו"ם תקיפה ובעל דינו אלם ואינו יכול להציל ממנו בדייני ישראל
>   יתבענו לדייני ישראל תחלה אם לא רצה לבא נוטל רשות מב"ד ומציל בדיני
>   עכו"ם מיד בעל דינו: הגה ויש רשות לב"ד לילך לפני עכו"ם ולהעיד שזה חייב
>   לזה (בה"ת בשם ר' שרירא) וכל זה דוקא כשאינו רוצה להיות ציית דין אבל
>   בלא"ה אסור לב"ד להרשות לדון לפני עכו"ם (מהרי"ק שורש א'):

so perhaps in that one case alone it would be ok

Comment: Totally irrelevant to the discussion. The OP is about serving as a criminal defense attorney, **defending** people in **criminal** court, not about being a litigation lawyer who goes after people for their money, in **civil** court.

Comment: You should deal with the case as asked by the OP. That is if the defendant may not br criminally liable in the gentile court but is halachically guilty.

Comment: @sabbahillel what r u talking about? we are talking about halacha

Comment: @IsraelReader where do see any diistinction between civil and criminal court in the rambam? its still a non-jewish court, and that is the point!!!!!!

Comment: @wowow The Rambam is speaking about a PLAINTIFF. The OP is speaking about a DEFENDANT.

Comment: @IsraelReader what evidence do you have that the rambam is only speaking of a plantiff?

Comment: @wowow The second paragraph implies someone who is trying to get money from the gentile. That is the plaintiff.

Comment: @sabbahillel that's because its only talking about a special case, meant to show what the law is in a very exact, specific situation where IF one was a plaintiff, and IF the defendant didn't want to go to jewish court, then they can go to secular court, the only way to illustrate that law, that its sometimes OK to go to secular court, would only make sense to illustrate it by a plaintiff, because he is demanding property, but that doesn't take away from the *first* paragraph, which is where the actual law is defined, which forbids jews to engage in secular courts, in **general**

Comment: @sabbahillel the pbasic law is defined the first sentence and there are only a few exceptions (mainly that second paragraph), that first sentence reads: "When **any person** has a judgment adjudicated by gentile judges and their courts, he is considered a wicked person"

Comment: @wowow The point is if a Jew is being sued in secular court, the implication is that it is not up to him. He would have to defend himself. He could try to take it to bais din, but if the plaintiff insists on secular court, he is probably forced to defend himself.

Comment: Simple logic. A person is always allowed to defend himself from loss. He is not obligated to lose out just because the case a plaintiff hauled him to a secular court. The same for criminal charges. A person always has a right to defend themselves.

Comment: @IsraelReader no that's not the case here, why would you assume someone "always has a chance to defend oneself"? even if that means that "he disgraced, blasphemed, and lifted up his hand against the Torah of Moses our teacher"? why, what source do you have to support that assertion?

Comment: @sabbahillel but this is talking about a non-jew, and this is talking about a JEW who should or should not, willingly, go to secular court, to defend a GOY who may not keep the noahide laws. yes the goy (or jew for that matter) may have to defend himself in court, but there's no reason a jewish person should **willingly** go to a secular court, transgressing the Torah, that JEW who is initallly making a life decision has the **Choice** to not go in the first place, and since there is a choice, and he is a jew, theres no reason he should fight other peoples battles, transgressing the torah

Comment: In the case of a defendant, he has NOT "disgraced, blasphemed, and lifted up his hand against the Torah of Moses". In the case of a civil case, the fault lies with the plaintiff, who took him to court, against the laws of the Torah, It is the plaintiff who lifted up his hand against the Torah of Moses. In a criminal case, the defendant also wasn't  given a choice. If it would be up to him, he would be at home, free. If you think that a person doesn't have a right to defend himself, (against the opinion of all the Poskim that I know of), then please provide a source for this outlandish notion.

Comment: @IsraelReader but we're not talking about whether the *defendant* can defend *himself*, the question concerns a potential *jewish lawyer* who would be *willingly* defending someone else, whether that person is jewish or non jewish, guilty or innocent, this question deals with a **potential jewish lawyer** who is making a life decision, and is under no direct, forced threat to go to court, he is making a decision to **willingly** go to fight other peoples battles, against the torah, why would such an act be permitted, if he has the clear choice not to, and if its other peoples battles anyway?

Comment: Fighting other people's battles, to help defend themselves from injustice, is NOT against the Torah. It is a MITZVAH.

Comment: @IsraelReader source? do all positive mitzvos override all negative mitzvos in all cases? what evidence do you have that the same would apply here, and especially **what evidence is there that it is permitted to transgress a commandment to help a goy who might not even keep the noachide laws**? There are many laws about not interacting with idolators at all, if one is stranded in a pit begging for help, we're not supposed to help them, why should the same apply here? if its literally a mitzvah than it should be an obligation for everyone to do so, what sources do you have for this exact case?

Comment: Secular courts operate in the framework of the 7 Nohaide laws, and Dina De'Malchuta Dina. Giving free legal services to a non-Jew may be an issur of "Lo Techaneim", however there is no Halachic issue with charging anyone for legal services that you provide them.

Comment: @IsraelReader "Secular courts operate in the framework of the 7 Nohaide laws" -- if only!!! secular courts support gay "rights", and it is NOT at all run under the understanidng the G-d gave the 7 mitzvos to Moshe at mount sinai, and we ar obligated to keep them, which is *an essential part of the fulfillment of the 7 laws*, do you have any source that says that all secular courts definitely currently keep the 7 mitzvos? also "however there is no Halachic issue with charging anyone for legal services that you provide them" -- what source is there for this?

Comment: I did not mean to say that secular courts keep the 7 mitzvos. I meant that a secular court is a legitimate institution for non-Jews (except in cases where they promote transgression of the Nohaide laws), since maintaining a judicial system is one of their 7 mitzvos. - Do you have a reason, why it should be prohibited to charge a non-Jew for legal services that you provide them in their court system, which they are allowed to have?

Comment: @IsraelReader yes I do have a reason for a JEW to work for a non-jew, even if that non-jew is allowed to be there, because the JEW is governmened by different laws than the non-jew, there are many cases where a JEW is forbidden to do business in general, there is a halacha in hilchos isurei machalos that its forbidden for a jew to open a busienss where he sells non-kosher animals [but if only SOME non kosher animals happen to get in, thats different than opening a business for it], even though non-kosher animals are OK for non jews, same thing here, theres a HALACHA for a JEW not to be incourt

Comment: @IsraelReader meaning, this halacha forbids a jew to do business with idolatruos (or even non-jewish) courts, if its a one-time deal perhaps it might bea different story, but there isa  halacha that a jew is not supposed to initially open a business that will be specifically for non-kosher things, including non-kosher courts, even if they are fine on the noahide level (just like non-kohser animals are fine for noahides)... and this question involves an entire career choice for a jew to make, which is pretty problematic